# How to load a file on component mounting using React w/ raw-loader

Tags: reactjs, raw-loader

I'm currently loading Markdown files using `raw-loader`.

`webpack.config.dev.js`

```js
rules: [
  ...
  {
    oneOf: [
      ...
      {test: /\.md$/, use: 'raw-loader'},
      ...
    ],
  },
],
```

Other than setting a map of renderers, the `Page` component should read a path from its props and delegate it to `ReactMarkdown`. Here the source is hard-coded to the content of `page/example.md`.

`src/components/page.js`

```rjsx
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import content from '../pages/example.md';

class Page extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactMarkdown source={content} />
    );
  }
}
```

`src/index.js`

```rjsx
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function Application() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Page source="home.md" />} />
      <Route exact path="/foo/" render={() => <Page source="foo.md" />} />
      <Route exact path="/bar/" render={() => <Page source="bar.md" />} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

How can I dynamically *raw-load* the path passed through props while `Page` is mounting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`src/components/page.js`

```js
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

class Page extends React.Component {

  state = {content: null};

  componentDidMount() {
    import('../pages/' + this.props.source).then(
      content => this.setState({content: content}),
      () => this.setState({content: null})
    );
  }

  render() {
    let { content } = this.state;
    return content ? (
      <ReactMarkdown renderers={renderers} source={content} />
    ) : null;
  }
}
```